# Как отрендерить AJAX ответ с помощью Django template?

Tags: django

Есть страница с мероприятиями и некоторое количество фильтров, хочется сделать фильтрацию без перезагрузки страницы. Только учусь и задумался над тем правильно ли я собираюсь делать реализацию AJAX в CMS Wagtail а Django. Как я понял рендер делается не силами шаблона а уже javascript. 
Мой план 
1. Делаю view возвращающую json 
2. Обрабатываю JSON и генерирую HTML

Проблема в том что разметка достаточно большая должна генерироваться, и рендер с помощью javascript кажется костыльным решением.

Просьба описать правильный workflow

Comment: возможно рендерить html во view и на странице подставлять этот кусок куда хотите. пример https://stackoverflow.com/a/18976471/5201699

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, шаблонизатор работает на бэкенде. Если данных много и разметка сложная, то стоит использовать какой-либо фронтенд-фреймворк, например React.